Setting a price to create SPL Tokens
I built a frontend platform for users to create & launch SPL tokens, but I'm stuck on one final part.
I want to charge an additional fee (Other then the network fee) for each time someone uses the platform.
How could I go about adding this? Currently they connect wallet, upload logo, enter information, then pick additional options.
Once they go to mint, I want to add a one time .2 SOL fee they pay that goes to my wallet at the same time they complete the transaction and get the tokens.
Thank you!!

you just have to add a transfer instruction in the transaction. You have an example on this page : https://solana.com/docs/core/transactions
